# Parallel.For loop exits too soon

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, parallel.for

I am trying to add all the tasks in a list parallelly and then await on them. Code for that:

```
List<Task<bool>> tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();                

Parallel.For(0, 500, file =>
{
  tasks.Add(SomeTask());
});

Console.WriteLine("Total tasks = " + tasks.Count);
```

When I execute the following code, sometimes I get the size of task list(tasks.Count) as 493  or 500 or 498. But it's not deterministic. What should I do?

Comment: You should stop using a shared non-threadsafe list in those tasks. `List<T>` is not thread-safe. Either add a lock around your code that manipulates the shared list, use a proper synchronized collection, or do something entirely different that doesn't need the list (with so little information in the question this last option is too vague to give any more hint for).

Comment: Basically, the for-loop didn't exit too soon, but the list additions were not synchronized and thus some of the updates were lost. Most probably, if you were to look at the tasks inside, you're going to find other strange things as well, such as duplicate entries or null-references.

Comment: When you print total task the remaining task has not finished yet. So you get these different values. As mentioned use thread-safe tasks.

Comment: @SerhatOz No, that's not right, he's only adding the tasks to the list, but his use of a non-threadsafe list means he'll lose some of the tasks in the process. He's not counting completed tasks. In other words, whether 0, 250 or all 500 tasks have completed or not doesn't matter in relation to the outcome here, nor for what he has attempted to do. Also, there's no such concept as a "thread-safe task". Tasks in the world of .NET are already thread-safe, but of course they can be related to code that is not.

Comment: `List<T>` (`List<Task<bool>>` in your case) is *not thread safe*; executing `Add` within `Parallel.For` is *dangerous* and may well result in unpredictable behavior

Comment: I'm pretty sure a good duplicate for this question exists here on Stack Overflow, which is why I'm not going to post an answer for it. I'm not able to find it, however, so if anyone can find one please vote to close it.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen thanks for the quick reply. Very well explained. What should I use instead of lists? Can I use array?

Comment: Try *PLinq* (Parallel Linq) instead of `Parallel.For`: `List<Task<bool>> tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 500).AsParallel().Select(file => SomeTask()).ToList();`

Comment: @Saurabh Shah: Technically you can use an array: `<Task<bool>>[] tasks = new <Task<bool>>[500]; Parallel.For(0, tasks.Length, index => { tasks[index] = SomeTask(); });` however, a better choice is either use *PLinq* or concurrent collections

Comment: The thread-safe collections avaidable in the  `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace are: 

`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, `BlockingCollection<T>`, `ConcurrentStack<T>`, `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, `ConcurrentBag<T>`,
`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`

Comment: Most commnly used are ConcurrentBag, Stack and Queue when fifo/lifo has to be involved.

Comment: Aside from the comments about List and thread-safety, there is absolutely no gain in using parallel.For() to add 500 items to a List.

Answer (score 1):

You have what is called a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You're accessing the list from multiple threads without synchronization, which causes it to be in a weird state.

You can use a thread-safe object like a ConcurrentStack instead (or ConcurrentBag or ConcurrentQueue, depending on wwhat you do with the collection):

```
ConcurrentStack<Task<bool>> tasks = new ConcurrentStack<Task<bool>>();                

Parallel.For(0, 500, file =>
{
  tasks.Push(SomeTask());
});

Console.WriteLine("Total tasks = " + tasks.Count);
```

Comment: why concurrent stack? closest collection to list is concurrent bag.

Comment: The thread-safe collection avaidable in the  `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace are: 

`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, `BlockingCollection<T>`, `ConcurrentStack<T>`, `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, `ConcurrentBag<T>`,
`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`

Comment: Stack felt most appropriate to me. Almost any of the concurrent collections would've worked for what he asked.

Answer (score 1):

Task-returning methods (e.g., `SomeTask`) generally return extremely quickly, and parallelizing their invocations generally results in *slower* execution.

It's much more normal for collections of tasks to be built up with (non-parallel) LINQ:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 500).Select(file => SomeTask()).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Total tasks = " + tasks.Count);
```

**If** your task-returning method has some CPU-bound code and you **do** need to run `SomeTask` on a thread pool thread, then you can use parallelism. One simple approach is to wrap the call in `Task.Run`:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 500).Select(file => Task.Run(() => SomeTask())).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Total tasks = " + tasks.Count);
```